# How to fix FileSystemException: Creation Failed (permission denied, errno = 13) in flutter setup

Tags: bash, macos, flutter

Flutter is crashing every time I run `flutter create my_app`. I keep getting permission errors that I think is related to either my PATH env variable or folder/file read, write, execute access. I’ve successfully downloaded and installed everything from the [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) but I can’t figure out how to fix this issue.

After installing flutter and its various dependencies, I run `flutter doctor -v` and it finishes with no errors:

```
...
No issues found!
```

But trying to run the `create` command outputs this error to the crash log:

```
...
FileSystemException: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = ‘/Users/<my_username>/Documents/Projects/flutter/my_app’ (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
...
```

I tried using these change mode commands as a fix but the issue persisted:

```
chmod -R -v o+w flutter/
```

```
chmod -R -v a+rwx flutter/
```

To see the full output of my error messages, check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37290) I posted.

This is the last step in my setup process so I can start learning flutter so any advice/help is appreciated.

Comment: And `Documents/Projects` exists in your home? Can you manually created `my_app` there, or do you get the permission error too?

Comment: @user1934428 I hadn’t tried that but it seems to have worked if I use the command in my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was facing the same error and couldn't figure out the cause.
Event googling didn't help.

You can try to use the alternate version of flutter or changing to a different channel like

```
flutter channel beta
```

or

```
flutter channel dev
```

or

```
flutter channel master
```

or

```
flutter channel stable
```

Also when you are running command

```
chmod -R -v a+rwx flutter/
```

make sure you are located in the parent folder of flutter from command line otherwise use it like the following

```
chmod -R -v a+rwx ‘/Users/<my_username>/Documents/Projects/flutter/’
```

Also if the above doesn't works then try changing the owner of folder flutter

```
chown -R yourusername:yourgroup ‘/Users/<my_username>/Documents/Projects/flutter/’
```

This may not be the appropriate answer but it should solve your issue for now.

Thanks :)